# Flushing old data on every change event

Tags: angularjs

I have four radio buttons. On select of  every radio button, i need to clear the old data and get new data from DB. How can i achieve this? 
$destroy can be used for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the value to a controller's property, via `ng-model`, and then set a `$scope.$watch`.

Comment: how to flush old data?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = [...];
```

then on click on the radiobutton, call the db, and apply new data

```
$http(...)
  .then(function (result) {
    $scope.data = result
  });
```

old data replaced with new data